# Unable to click on the dropdown elements by selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I tried so many things but not able to click the dropdown elements.The dropdown is not a select type. I can find the element but not able to click on it.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".quantumWizMenuPaperselectDropDown.exportDropDown")).click();
            
//WebElement slot=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-value,'5:30 -6 PM')] [1]"));
//Thread.sleep(3000);       
//Actions act= new Actions(driver);
//act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-value,'3:30 -4 PM')] [1]"))).build().perform();
//act.click();
//Thread.sleep(3000);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-value,'5:30 -6 PM')] [1]")).click();
                
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(40));
WebElement times=wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-value,'5:30 -6 PM')] [1]")));
times.click();
```

Comment: Please share the HTML of the dropdown section.

Comment: Not being able to click it is too ambiguous of a problem description. What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.